# Why do I have extra values on X-axis, with bar plot?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-express

There are only [3,4,5,6,8] values for Cylinders in `Auto.csv`, but when I created a bar plot using plotly, I see that there is one extra value for Cylinder over X-axis which is 7.

How to eliminate that additional point?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Following is the screenshot of the code executed]

Comment: Try to put `cylinders` as a string` ['3','4','5','6','8'] `, and not as a number ` [3,4,5,6,8] `..

Comment: Please add your code as text, otherwise I cannot be properly indexed by search engines.

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your axis type to `categorical` which prevents Plotly from filling your "missing" values.

```
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
```

### [image]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/mtcars.csv')
df_mean = df[['cyl', 'mpg']].groupby('cyl').mean().reset_index()

fig = px.bar(df_mean, 'cyl', 'mpg')
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.show()
```